# Spring Security headers filters and status codes response

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

I'm new for Spring and Spring Security.

I implemented a custom filter to manage the custom Authentication.

For this custom Authentication I used `org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`
and and I expect to find a token into the `Authorization` header.

Is it a bad idea to add an other filter to check only if the `Authorization` header is filled?
Is already there some filters to have this?

For my custom `Authorization`, I already implemented a check for `Authorization` header. In case it not filled I will throw an '`AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException`'.  I expected to receive for this a `400` or `401` status but I'm receive `500` and I see my exception trace. 
Probably is this exception not automatically handled by Spring Security?

One more question, for a bad token (not `Authorized`) I'm using `BadCredentialsException` but I'm receiving `403`.

Is it possible to have a `401` or have I to implement a custom Exceptions handing?

Comment: chaining of filters is not a bad idea at all. Spring does this internally like many times

Comment: YOur filter should be part of the spring security filter chain and not a regular filter. Also you might want to extend (I strongly suggest it) one of the base filter from Spring Security as that will give you more integration into Spring Security (and the error handling, event firing etc.).